# Faraday waves and Chladni plates

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics, resonance, vibrations

I am a High school student who's writing a research paper about Faraday waves and Chladni plates. I've been doing a lot of research on Faraday waves specifically, as there aren't many sources that can explain to me the Faraday waves phenomenon appropriately at my level without giving some bizarre equations that I've never seen before in my physics class.

The link below seems like a very good source to understand Faraday waves but as I said earlier it uses equations that i am not familiar with or should be familiar with having only a high school physics background. All i've learned from the presentation is that Faraday waves are formed **due to the inertia of the fluid** as the vessel moves up and down creating deformations on the surface of the fluid.

http://nldlab.gatech.edu/w/images/9/95/ProjectFaraday2.pdf

I was specifically looking at how I can achieve different patterns at X frequency for fluids with **different densities** and compare it to a circular Chladni plate pattern with the same frequency X.

I know that the Chladni plate and the fluids have different densities but **is it still possible to achieve the same pattern on a fluid and on the Chladni plate with the same frequency of X?**

Thank you, the sooner the better, im quite short on time.